# NPM: Change the `bin` output directory for the node modules

Tags: node.js, npm

Currently, if you are using a `package.json` file to manage your project's dependencies (whatever project it is, may it be a ruby, php, python or js app), by default everything is installed under `./node_modules`.

When some dependencies have binaries to save, they're installed under `./node_modules/.bin`.

What I need is a feature that allow me to change the `./node_modules/.bin` directory for `./bin`.

Simple example:

A PHP/Symfony app has a `./vendor` dir for Composer dependencies, and all binaries are saved in `./bin`, thanks to the `config: { bin-dir: bin }` option in `composer.json`.

But if I want to use Gulp to manage my assets, I create a `package.json` file, require all my dependencies and then run `npm install`.
Then, my wish is to run `bin/gulp` to execute gulp, but actually I have to run `node_modules/.bin/gulp` which is not as friendly as `bin/gulp`.

I've looked at package.json examples/guides on [browsenpm.org](http://browsenpm.org/package.json#bin) and [docs.npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), but none of them works, because they are here to define your own project's binaries. But I don't have any binaries, because I want to use binaries from *other* libraries.

Is there an option for that with NodeJS/NPM ?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding gulp tasks to your `package.json`.

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build-templates": "gulp build-templates",
    "minify-js": "gulp minify-js"
  }
}
```

You can run any scripts specified in `package.json` by simply running the following:

> $ npm run build-templates
>   $ npm run minify-js

You get the idea. You can use the `gulp` command inside the string without doing `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` because npm is smart enough to put all scripts from `./node_modules/.bin/` into the path for that script execution.

Comment: It's not "the" solution, but it is "a" solution, and I did not think that it would work. 
Can we pass parameters to these scripts ? If so, we could do this :
`{ "scripts": { "gulp": "gulp" } }`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can pass multiple parameters to `npm run`.